# How to get the equivalent Stanford-Core-nlp Python output in Java

Tags: python, java, stanford-nlp

I have a function in Python like this-

```
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(host + ":" + port)
text = "Joshua Brown, 40, was killed in Florida in May when his Tesla failed to " \
       "differentiate between the side of a turning truck and the sky while " \
       "operating in autopilot mode."
output = nlp.annotate(
    text,
    properties={
        "outputFormat": "json",
        "annotators": "depparse,ner,entitymentions,sentiment"
    }
)
pprint(output)
```

and it get the output like so-

```
{
  'sentences': [
    {
      'basicDependencies': [
        {
          'dep': 'ROOT',
          'dependent': 7,
          'dependentGloss': 'killed',
          'governor': 0,
          'governorGloss': 'ROOT'
        },
        {
          'dep': 'compound',
          'dependent': 1,
          'dependentGloss': 'Joshua',
          'governor': 2,
          'governorGloss': 'Brown'
        },
        …
      ],
      'enhancedDependencies': [
        {
          'dep': 'ROOT',
          'dependent': 7,
          'dependentGloss': 'killed',
          'governor': 0,
          'governorGloss': 'ROOT'
        },
        {
          'dep': 'compound',
          'dependent': 1,
          'dependentGloss': 'Joshua',
          'governor': 2,
          'governorGloss': 'Brown'
        },
```

But I wanted to do the same thing in Java, so I wrote a java method like-

```
public class NlpTest implements RequestHandler<Input,Output>{
    public static String text = "Multiple locations in Maharashtra linked to state transport minister Anil Parab were raided this morning by the Enforcement Directorate (ED) as part of a money-laundering probe relating to alleged irregularities in a land deal.";


    @Override
    public Output handleRequest(Input input, Context context) {


        String output="";
        try {
            System.out.println("entering method handleRequest");
            System.out.println("text = " + text);

            Properties props = new Properties();
            //props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, tokensregex, sentiment");           //------>here
            props.setProperty("annotators", "depparse,ner,entitymentions,sentiment");
            props.setProperty("ner.additional.tokensregex.rules","src/main/java/custom.rules");

//            props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
            props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "false");
            props.setProperty("outputFormat", "json");



            StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);


            CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument(text);
            // annotate
            pipeline.annotate(doc);
            System.out.println("pipeline="+pipeline.toString());
            System.out.println("doc.entityMentions() = " + doc.entityMentions());
            // display tokens
            for (CoreLabel tok : doc.tokens()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s\t%d\t%d", tok.word(), tok.beginPosition(), tok.endPosition()));
            }
```

I get individual fields as output, but I want to obtain the direct JSON output which I obtained from the Python method.My question is how to do this in Java.
Whatever thing above I am doing in Python, how to do that in Java?
I am new to Stanford-core-NLP and any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to already be conversant with Java.  Is it sufficient to point you to `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter`, or do you need more than that?

https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/JSONOutputter.html

You can find an example of use in: `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputterTest`.